# C# How to update an access table

Tags: c#, database, ms-access-2010

How should the UPDATE statement with multiple columns, 
that have to be updated?
(Because a row has changed a lot of it in it)

I tried some search on this board, but in the other questions were sometimes "[ ]" around the columns, sometimes not, but both versions don´t work in my code.

Here´s the code:

```
            try 
            {
                string name = mtb_Name.Text.ToString();
                string altname = mtb_AltName.Text.ToString();
                string licht = cb_Licht.SelectedItem.ToString();
                string boden = cb_Boden.SelectedItem.ToString();
                string haerte = cb_Haerte.SelectedItem.ToString();
                string pg = cb_PG.SelectedItem.ToString();
                string hoehe = mtb_Hoehe.Text.ToString();
                string form = cb_Form.SelectedItem.ToString();
                string zuechter = cb_Zuechter.SelectedItem.ToString();
                string land = cb_Land.SelectedItem.ToString();
                string gruppe = cb_Gruppe.SelectedItem.ToString();

//the connection works, I can add stuff in other tables and delete stuff everywhere

                parent.GetDBConnection().Open();
                OleDbCommand Query = new OleDbCommand();
                Query.Connection = parent.GetDBConnection();
                Query.Parameters.Clear();

//I build this string at the moment for testing purposes only and 
//converted everything and putted in a string to be sure.
//later it will be replaced with the Parameters.Add(,)
//I also did test it with [AltNameRose] as columname instead of AltNameRose
//or wrote instead of the ' ' a "\"" around the strings, 
//but doesn´t seem to be the problem.

                Query.CommandText = "UPDATE tb_Rose SET" +
                    " ,AltNameRose = '" + altname +
                    "' ,NameZuechter = '" + haerte +
                    "' ,Boden = '" + boden +
                    "' ,Wuchshoehe = '" + hoehe +
                    "' ,Farbe = '" + " " +
                    "' ,Foto = '" + " " +
                    "' ,Licht = '" + licht +
                    "' ,Preisgruppe = '" + pg +
                    "' ,Gruppe = '" + gruppe +
                    " WHERE NameRose = '" + name + "'";

//the CommandText seems to be missing something, but I don´t know what.

                MessageBox.Show(Query.CommandText.ToString());
                Query.ExecuteNonQuery();
                parent.GetDBConnection().Close();
                MessageBox.Show("Rose successfully edited.");
                this.Close();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
                parent.GetDBConnection().Close();
            }
```

The thrown exception is

> "Syntaxerror in UPDATE-Command

The table tb_Rose looks like this:
NameRose|AltNameRose|NameZuechter|Frosthaerte|Boden|Wuchshoehe|Farbe|Foto||Licht|Preisgruppe|Gruppe

On another question stood, that the order, 
how I pass the columns is important too, 
but it doesn´t work out for me.

Has anyone a small hint where the mistake is?

Comment: after set there is a `,`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need comma *just* before your first column. That's why your;

```
" ,AltNameRose = '"
```

should be

```
" AltNameRose = '"
```

But more important, you should always use [parameterized queries](http://blog.codinghorror.com/give-me-parameterized-sql-or-give-me-death/). This kind of string concatenations are open for [SQL Injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) attacks.

Also use [`using` statement](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02.aspx) to dispose your connections and commands automatically instead of calling `.Close()` methods manually.

Comment: Thanks...I feel dumb for not seeing that :/ I will do so with the parameterizing when it´s working.

Answer (score 0):

The syntax of Update statement is

```
Update table_name SET
                  column_name = value,
                  column_name = value,
                  ....
                  Where condition
```

In your query You put a `,` after the SET keyword.

there is a `,` after the SET keyword.. try below code

```
Query.CommandText = "UPDATE tb_Rose SET" +
                    " AltNameRose = '" + altname +
                    "' ,NameZuechter = '" + haerte +
                    "' ,Boden = '" + boden +
                    "' ,Wuchshoehe = '" + hoehe +
                    "' ,Farbe = '" + " " +
                    "' ,Foto = '" + " " +
                    "' ,Licht = '" + licht +
                    "' ,Preisgruppe = '" + pg +
                    "' ,Gruppe = '" + gruppe +
                    " WHERE NameRose = '" + name + "'";
```

Comment: Thanks for finding my mistake and the example.